# User Login with roles not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, html, session, session-cookies

I have created a table in my db as user and I have assigned the accounts with the user types as Admin,User,Vendor.

I have 3 seperate dashboards created for each of the roles. When I login to the system the redirection works totally fine.
But when I insert the url of the dashboard of the another type of user the page loads without any redirection.

when I log in as User and if I insert the following url in the browser admin page loads for a general user.

```
http://localhost:3002/Admin/dashboard.php
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong in my code.

This is my php code for login control

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    include('./validate.php');
    require_once('../Includes/db/dbConnection.php');
    $db = DBConnection::getInstance();
    $connection = $db->getConnection();

    if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
        $username=validate($_POST['uname']);
        $pass=validate($_POST['psw']);
        
        $sql="SELECT userId,userType FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
        $res=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($res)>0;
        if($count>0){
            $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['userId']=$row['userId'];
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['userType']=$row['userType'];
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']='true';
            switch ($_SESSION['userType']){
                case 'User':
                    header("location: ../User/dashboard.php");
                    break;
                case 'Admin':
                    header("location: ../Admin/dashboard.php");
                    break;
                case 'Vendor':
                    header("location: ../Vendor/dashboard.php");
                    break;
                default:
                   
                    break;
            }
        }else{
           $_SESSION['status']='Wrong Username/Password';
           header("Location: ../login.php"); 
        }
    }

?>
```

This is the code I use in the dashboard.php file for each user.

Admin

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn']!='true' && $_SESSION['userType']!='Admin'){
        header("Location: ../login.php");
    }  
?>
```

User

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn']!='true' && $_SESSION['userType']!='User'){
        header("Location: ../login.php");
    }  


?>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Ok I will make that change. Thank you

Comment: I have inserted it in the question above as Admin and User separately . Not sure whether I am doing it wrong ?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OR in this check not AND

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || 
    $_SESSION['loggedIn']!='true' ||
    $_SESSION['userType']!='User')
{
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yess. It worked. Can you explain what's the difference between those two ? I wanted all the 3 condition to be true . With the knowledge I have OR returns true if at least 1 condition is true and AND returns true if and only if all the conditions are true. So whats the difference?

Comment: Well all 3 can be true, but if one is not true you should not be in this dashboard

Comment: @Dharman It was :) Nice to know you are checking up on me